# Go mail sender inside bash, triggered by cron

Tags: linux, bash, go, cron

I have a Go program that sends mail to me.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
    "os"
)

func main() {
        send(os.Args[2] + " program completed.", os.Args[1], os.Args[2], os.Args[3])
}

func send(body string, to string, s string, date string) {
    from := "foo@gmail.com"
    pass := "bar"
    msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
        "To: " + to + "\n" +
        "Subject: "+ s + " main\n\n" +
        body + "\n" + date

    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("smtp error: %s", err)
        return
    }

    log.Print("sent, visit mail address: "+to)
}
```

And a bash script that runs it with a mailing list for future preparation,

```
Do things.....
.
.
filename='list'
while read line; do
# reading each line of list
echo "$(date '+%d-%m-%Y-%T') Mail sent to address : $line" >> ${now}-log.log
./mailsend ${line} foo ${date}
done < $filename

Do final things .....
```

As you can see that there are simple log attempts to see if the program worked well.
And there are no errors.

When I trigger the program by hand, it works perfectly but from the bash script which is triggered by a cronjob it does not work.

Any suggestions ?

edit1: Variables are solid. Manuel trigger works as intended. When triggered by cron, I do not receive mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to `cd` to your directory before calling `./mailsend`?

Comment: I had the cd in cron as ` cd /foo/bar && bash /foo/bar/script.sh` . The thing is the mailsender program is located in the /foo/bar/baz. correcto, enjoy the points.